# rails cache vs redis on performance, ease to use, persistence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis

I know redis is powerful and I use it for caching in my rails application. Could anyone give me an comparison between rails default caching and redis? What's the trade off as cache.

Comment: Read this article http://www.nateberkopec.com/2015/07/15/the-complete-guide-to-rails-caching.html  There is a comparison for memcached, redis, memstore & filestore

Answer (score 1):

The main point is distribution.

With Redis the cache can be shared across all back-ends (eventually running on multiple hosts). This is the most scalable solution (because you can multiply the number of back-end hosts). The downside is you will pay for an extra network roundtrip for each cache access. Also, you require an extra component to deploy and manage (Redis).

With ActiveSupport::FileStore, the cache can be shared across back-ends instances provided they run on the same host. Easy to use.

With ActiveSupport::MemStore, the cache cannot be shared across back-ends (even if they run on the same host). However, this is the fastest solution. Easy to use.

Comment: this is not true if you use memcache as your Rails cache backend